# Передать onclick ajax запросом методом GET

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, get

Здравствуйте.

Перегуглил и не нашел нигде ответа. Подскажите, как в ссылке спомощью jQuery передать GET запрос, но без всяких функций. А если без функции никак, тогда какой-нибудь универсальной функцией, чтобы можно было выбрать, куда и что передать.

```
<a id="opener" href='#' onclick="$.ajax( '?act=massmail&active', { one: 'one', php: 'php', jquery: 'jquery' });">Активные</a>
```

**Добавлено из комментария.**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.20/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.20/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
    // increase the default animation speed to exaggerate the effect
    $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "blind",
            hide: "explode"
        });

        $("#opener").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<a id="opener" href='#' onclick="Тут некий код который передаст в мольное окно GET из PHP цикла">item1</a>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>
        <?php echo $_GET[ 'code']; ?>тут отображается содержимое модального окна, А самое главное GET'ы</p>
</div>
```

Comment: с трудом понимаю, что вам нужно, но возможно это поможет: [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax)

     .--.
       /    \
      ## a  a
      (   '._)
       |'-- |
     _.\___/_   ___pjax___
   ."\> \Y/|<'.  '._.-'
  /  \ \_\/ /  '-' /
  | --'\_/|/ |   _/
  |___.-' |  |`'`
    |     |  |
    |    / './
   /__./` | |
      \   | |
       \  | |
       ;  | |
       /  | |
 jgs  |___\_.\_
      `-"--'---'

Comment: Мне нужно поймать GET запросы в модальном окне jquery и далее их обработать php

Comment: Присоединяюсь к @Spectre. Собственно не вижу, где тут может быть проблема. Попробуйте чуть подробнее описать. Откуда берется модальное окно: iframe, генерируется в связи с каким-то действием или же изначально прописано на странице но скрыто до определенного события и т.д.

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Comment: При клике по ссылке и так формируется GET запрос. Что ещё-то надо?

Answer (score 2):

Ох, попросил подробней описать... Ваш ник подойдёт к моей реакции - сразил и при том наповал )))

Ладно, насколько понял, на столько и попробовал решить вашу задачу. В примере по ссылке - http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/82tze/1/ - можно  глянуть, как это работает.

**HTML**

```
<a id="opener" href='#' rel="on">Кликни меня!</a>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
// это как бы ответ от обработчика
var ajaxResponse = '<a href="http://site.ru/?param=1">Link 1</a><br /><a href="http://site.ru/?param=2">Link 2</a><br /><a href="http://site.ru/?param=3">Link 3</a>';

$(function () {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: 'blind',
        hide: 'explode'
    });

    $("#opener").click(function () {
        // берем нужные данные для передачи в обработчик
        // предположим, что эти данные в атрибуте rel
        var someVal = $(this).attr('rel');
        // для себя - смотрим, что получили
        alert('Будем передавать параметр: ' + someVal);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/html/', // путь к одработчику (прописать свой)
            data: {domeKey: someVal}, // передаваемые параметры в обработчик
            type: 'POST', // или GET - метод передачи данных
            dataType: 'html', // тип данных в ожидаемом ответе
            success: function(data){
                // на самом деле, в data находится именно ваш ожидаемы ответ
                // от обработчика, но т.к. мы тут реальный ответ
                // использовать не можем, то используем ответ
                // созданный вручную - переменная ajaxResponse
                $('#dialog').dialog('open').html(ajaxResponse);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Почти то что нужно, но есть но.
Обработчик это та же самая страница!
А как этот сделать универсальным, так что бы в самой ссылке передавать то что необходимо а именно get. Я бы обошелся PHP но этот jquery-dialog не понимает простого передаваемого get обычной ссылкой.
А мне просто необходимо передать в это модальное окно php переменные.

Comment: Какая разница где обработчик? Пусть будет в этом же файле. Во-вторых, вы постоянно говорите о каком-то "*GET*" - объясните, что вы под этим подрозумеваете, а то я старенький и некоторые жаргонные выражения не понимаю )) И в-третьих, если вы хотите определить значение какой-то ранее прописанной переменной в блоке модального окна, то из JS это сделать не удасться. Формируйте данные+html в ответе (PHP) или JS и вставляйте их в блок.

Comment: Может я не догоняю и тут аякс и не нужен, что меня на нем переклинило.
<?php
foreach (file(somefile.txt) as $line)
{
$qw = explode ("|", $line)
echo '<a id="opener" href="?act=massmail&code=0588069805&mail=1&item=5&somestring=false">';
}
?>
И вот таких ссылок 100-200 
Это некая редактируемая база пользователей и в диалоговое всплывающее окно нужно передать все переменные методом GET что собственно из самой ссылки понятно.

Comment: только мне получать с модального окна ничего не надо, нужно в него только передать

Comment: Вызывать так <a href="#" class="opener"  get="?act=massmail&code=0588069805&item=2&link=ya.ru" name="Название окна" >Открыть окно</a>

и теперь в php делаем так:
if (isset($_GET['link']))
{
//тут свой код
}

Но есть проблема:
При вызове модального окна в окне грузить весь сайт + вызываемое $_GET['link']
Подскажите может есть решение грузить только желаемое со сраницы.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
      var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
         .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Attraction Details',
            modal:true,
            width: 800,
            height:500
         });
      $('.opener').click(function() {

          var prname=this.name
          $dialog.dialog('option', 'title', prname);
          $dialog.load($(this).attr('get')); // загружаю из тега get
         $dialog.dialog('open');
         return false;
      });
   });
   </script>
```

Вызывать так

```
<a href="#" class="opener" get="?act=massmail&code=0588069805&item=2&link=ya.ru" name="Название окна" >Открыть окно</a>
```

и теперь в php делаем так: `if (isset($_GET['link'])) { //тут свой код }`

Но есть проблема: При вызове модального окна в окне грузить весь сайт + вызываемое $_GET['link'] Подскажите может есть решение грузить только желаемое со сраницы.